# Unable to read and load JSON file in Python , JSON format is different

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the JSON in below format, I'm unable to read and load the JSON file.Getting extra data error. Please help

```
{"From":{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"e203b3e0-0b89- 11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137","name":"Bot","aadObjectId":null,"role":"bot"},"To": 
{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"deb09575-8edb-411f-b875-418e7944a315","name":"User","aadObjectId":null,"role":"user"},"Text":""}
{"From":{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137","name":"Bot","aadObjectId":null,"role":"bot"},"To": 
{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"a23f6775-c557-489d-996a-d6d3b329a234","name":"User","aadObjectId":null,"role":"user"},"Text":"Let me know if there’s anything else you need."}
{"From":{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137","name":"Bot","aadObjectId":null,"role":"bot"},"To": 
{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"a9f3d513-e4d2-48dc-996a-df3c292e707c","name":"User","aadObjectId":null,"role":"user"},"Text":"I’m here if you need anything else."}
{"From":{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137","name":"Bot","aadObjectId":null,"role":"bot"},"To": 
{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"b08c1237-82cb-4550-8b19-cef5a8e87439","name":"User","aadObjectId":null,"role":"user"},"Text":""}
{"From":{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137","name":"Bot","aadObjectId":null,"role":"bot"},"To": 
{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"7eb76928-1a0e-4e31-80b2-519be0315d56","name":"User","aadObjectId":null,"role":"user"},"Text":""}
```

Code :

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

##Date Format
date_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%M" 

#ft = 'C:/Users/abc/Desktop/xyz/pqr/aaa/Data5.json'
#data = json.dumps(ft)
#data = json.load(json.dumps(ft))

##Read the JSON file
with open('C:/Users/abc/Desktop/xyz/pqr/aaa/Data5.json',encoding= "utf-8") as f:
    #data = json.loads(json.dumps([f]))
    data = json.load(f)
```

Error

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

Comment: what you show is not valid JSON

Comment: These are bunch of JSON Objects, each one valid JSON itself. You probably need these in a JSON Array, separated by comma

Comment: ```data[340:360] ===> 
',"Text":""}\n   {"Fro'
``` ... the format of the data isn't right. There should be a comma separating dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the json objects into an array and properly separate the objects with commas:

```
[
{"From":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"e203b3e0-0b89- 11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137",
      "name":"Bot","aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"bot"},
  "To":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"deb09575-8edb-411f-b875-418e7944a315",
      "name":"User",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"user"},
  "Text":""},
{"From":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137",
      "name":"Bot",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"bot"},
  "To":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"a23f6775-c557-489d-996a-d6d3b329a234",
      "name":"User",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"user"},
  "Text":"Let me know if there’s anything else you need."},
{"From":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137",
      "name":"Bot",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"bot"},
  "To":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"a9f3d513-e4d2-48dc-996a-df3c292e707c",
      "name":"User",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"user"},
  "Text":"I’m here if you need anything else."},
{"From":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137",
      "name":"Bot",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"bot"},
  "To":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"b08c1237-82cb-4550-8b19-cef5a8e87439",
      "name":"User",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"user"},
  "Text":""},
{"From":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"e203b3e0-0b89-11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137",
      "name":"Bot",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"bot"},
  "To":
    {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema",
      "id":"7eb76928-1a0e-4e31-80b2-519be0315d56",
      "name":"User",
      "aadObjectId":null,
      "role":"user"},
  "Text":""}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid json:

```
{"From":{"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"e203b3e0-0b89- 11ea-b608-f5b0a8eb5137","name":"Bot","aadObjectId":null,"role":"bot"},"To":
   {"$type":"Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema","id":"deb09575-8edb-411f-b875-418e7944a315","name":"User","aadObjectId":null,"role":"user"},"Text":""}
```

But you have many of them so json still finds data after reading an object and chokes on that.

In fact you can read the file 2 lines at a time:

```
   ...
   ##Read the JSON file
   with open('C:/Users/abc/Desktop/xyz/pqr/aaa/Data5.json',encoding= "utf-8") as f:
       data = []            # initialize an empty list
       for line in f:
           line += next(f)  # concatenate every second line
           data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this produces the data you need.

```
>>> new_data = '[' + re.sub(r"\}\s*\{", "}, {", data) + ']'
>>> json_data = json.loads(new_data)
```

Just need to cook the data a bit. Assuming this is a catenation of several JSON packets, we can separate them with proper syntax, and make it into a JSON compatible list with square braces.

```
>>> json_data[2]['From']['$type']
'Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Schema'
```

Comment: Its still throwing the error, raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: Fix it then @sanjanajha, you know how to debug right?